# What is the pythonic way to overload a class without using external modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, math

Consider the following class:

```
class Vector2():
    def __init__(self, x: float = 0, y: float = 0) -> None:
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

In this example, how would I override **__mul__** so it can work with both scalars and another Vector2?

My initial approach was to use the **isinstance** function to check if the other variable I'm multiplying with is an **int** or a **float**. This works, but still, using the **isinstance** function with a bunch of **else ifs** does not look optimal.

```
   def __mul__(self, other: object) -> Vector2:
        if isinstance(other, int) or isinstance(other, float):
            return Vector2(self.x * other, self.y * other)
        elif isinstance(other, Vector2):
            return Vector2(self.x * other.x, self.y * other.y)
        else:
            return NotImplemented
```

Python does have a built-in modules that allow "overloading" [for type-hinting purposes only](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) and there are [external libraries](https://pypi.org/project/overloading/) that can also solve this problem.

In this case, is there a more clean way to do it?

Comment: No. Python does not support overloading and the `@overload` decorator is for the type checker only (only the last implementation of the method will actually be executed). Your method looks fine to me.

Comment: `object` is the correct annotation; operator overloads are supposed to accept arbitrary other operands and return `NotImplemented` if they get an argument they don't understand (so that `else` case should be `return NotImplemented`, not `raise ...`).

Comment: Minor note: You can condense the first check to `if isinstance(other, (int, float)):`; if you give it a `tuple` of types, it'll return true if it's an instance of any of them.

Comment: should the last edit be reverted? for someone new reading this question and checking the comments later, the comments don't make sense without seeing the edit history, talking about this change `if isinstance(other, (int, float))` compared with the original one that used `or`

Comment: Yeah, I guess so... in a sense it's more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the `isinstance(other, (int, float))` you can use the [Number abc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html) to catch all number types regardless of specific implementation

```
import numbers
...
isinstance(other, numbers.Number)
```

or

```
isinstance(other, numbers.Real)
```

this way you don't have to specify if its a `int` or a `float` or whatever else like [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) of [Fraction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html)

As for your question, I don't see anything wrong with a bunch of `if-else` in this case, but if you want the standard library also have something for this: [functools.singledispatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) (py 3.4+) and [functools.singledispatchmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatchmethod) (py 3.8+) which is basically the same thing behind the scene

EDIT

In order to not need to define the others method outside of the class and so you can check for this class for the dispatch, you can define a base class which can implements some basic stuff and your main class which inherit from that and implement the important stuff

```
from functools import singledispatchmethod
from numbers import Real


class BaseVector2():

    def __init__(self, x: Real = 0, y: Real = 0) -> None:
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}(x={self.x}, y={self.y})"

class Vector2(BaseVector2):

    @singledispatchmethod
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return NotImplemented

    @__mul__.register
    def _(self,other:Real):
        print("numbers")
        return Vector2(self.x * other, self.y * other)
    
    @__mul__.register
    def _(self,other:BaseVector2):
        print("vector")
        return Vector2(self.x * other.x, self.y * other.y)
```

sample use

```
>>> x = Vector2(3, 2)
>>> y = Vector2(2, 2)
>>> print(x*2.5)
numbers
Vector2(x=7.5, y=5.0)
>>> print(x*2)
numbers
Vector2(x=6, y=4)
>>> print(x*y)
vector
Vector2(x=6, y=4)
>>> print(x*"boo")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module>
    print(x*"boo")
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'Vector2'
>>>
```

Comment: `numbers.Number` is almost always the wrong thing to check for. There's almost nothing that actually works for arbitrary `Number`s, unless it actually works for arbitrary objects. Particularly, there's no guarantee the vector can multiply `self.x` and `self.y` by an arbitrary `Number`.

Comment: The `numbers` module is almost entirely useless.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica how so? the point here is simple know that you get a numeric type and don't care for the specific, if you don't like `numbers.Number` then use `numbers.Real`, or whatever, is just to again avoid needed to list specifics one...

Comment: But you *do* need to know specifics. For example, you treat accepting `Decimal` as if it were a good thing, but you *cannot multiply* a `Decimal` and a `float`. Arbitrary instances of `Number` are *not interoperable*. Knowing an object is a `Number` doesn't mean you know enough to actually do anything useful with it.

Comment: Using `Real` doesn't help. Arbitrary instances of `Real` aren't interoperable either.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica well, then just be specific if knowing the exact type is relevant to your project, otherwise is on the user any unexpected resulting for unintended use

Comment: It clearly is relevant for this case! You can't perform the `self.x * other` and `self.y * other` multiplications with an arbitrary `Number`. There is *almost nothing* you can do with an arbitrary `Number`. (Same for `Real`.) Your `Number` suggestion is wrong for both the OP and for almost any other possible situation.

Comment: I don't see the problem here - yes, different number types aren't interoperable, in which case you'll get an exception with a message telling you so if you do this. But the chances are, all of the vectors in one program are going to have the same type of number. If it's for a reusable library, then being more permissive about number types means one user can have vectors of floats and another can have vectors of decimals, and both will work. If somebody mixes floats and decimals they will get an error either way.

Comment: @kaya3: `x` and `y` are still annotated as `float`. If the intent of the answer actually is to have a vector class where a vector of `Decimal`s can be multiplied by a `Decimal` and a vector of `float`s can be multiplied by a `float`, then the annotations need adjustment, and the vector class should probably be made generic. That's not the intent of the original code, though, and it's not clear whether that's Copperfield's intent.

Comment: yes, that is my intent... so basically the whole problem you have with my suggestion is that I forgot to remove the float annotation?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [`functools.singledispatchmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatchmethod) (only available in python 3.8+)

```
class Vector2():
    def __init__(self, x: float = 0, y: float = 0) -> None:
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @singledispatchmethod
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return NotImplemented

@Vector2.__mul__.register
def _(self, other: Vector2):
    print("I'm a vector")
    # return Vector2(self.x * other.x, self.y * other.y)


@Vector2.__mul__.register
def _(self, other: int):
    print("I'm an int")
    # return Vector2(self.x * other, self.y * other)


@Vector2.__mul__.register
def _(self, other: float):
    print("I'm a float")
    # return Vector2(self.x * other, self.y * other)
```

We decorate a default function in the main class and later add their implementation
by using

`@cls.f.register`

where `cls` is the class name and `f` is the name of the function

Now, typing this

```
x = Vector2(3, 2)
y = Vector2(2, 2)

print(x * y)
print(x * 2)
print(x * 2.5)
print(x*'a')
```

returns...

- I'm a vector
- I'm an int
- I'm a float
- TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'Vector2'

Comment: I update my answer to show a way to do it inside the class